# Determine total memory usage of embedded C program

Tags: c, memory, embedded

I would like to be able to debug how much total memory is being used by C program in a limited resource environment of 256 KB memory (currently I am testing in an emulator program).

I have the ability to print debug statements to a screen, but what method should I use to calculate how much my C program is using (including globals, local variables [from perspective of my main function loop], the program code itself etc..)?

A secondary aspect would be to display the location/ranges of specific variables as opposed to just their size.

-Edit- The CPU is Hitachi SH2, I don't have an IDE that lets me put breakpoints into the program.

Comment: What CPU & development environment? When I was developing for an ARM7 system, the IDE would output data on the project's memory usage after each successful build. The fact that we didn't use dynamic memory made matters easier too.

Comment: Hitachi SH2 - this is for an old game console. Dev env is Notepad++ and gcc

Comment: Your emulator may already have that information available.

Comment: You don't need an IDE to set breakpoints.  You do need a debugger. If you are using GCC then GDB is the defacto choice.  It can be run stand-alone as a command line debugger, via various graphical wrappers such as Insight, or via Eclipse for example.  How is your development host connected to the target? (e.g JTAG, serial, proprietary hardware debugger?).  Not that it matters in this case, access through the debugger is not in fact the answer to the question.

Comment: For the record, the stack pointer on SH2 is R15. You can determine it using an asm function such as: `! int _get_stack_pointer()
  .align  4
  .global _get_stack_pointer
_get_stack_pointer: 
  mov     r15,r0   !copy stack pointer to return value
  rts
  nop` and in your header file you can declare the function like `extern int get_stack_pointer();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the IDE options make the proper actions (mark a checkobx, probably) so that the build process (namely, the linker) will generate a map file.
A map file of an embedded system will normally give you the information you need in a detailed fashion: The memory segments, their sizes, how much memory is utilzed in each one, program memory, data memory, etc.. There is usually a lot of data supplied by the map file, and you might need to write a script to calculate exactly what you need, or copy it to Excel. The map file might also contain summary information for you.

The stack is a bit trickier. If the map file gives that, then there you have it. If not, you need to find it yourself. Embedded compilers usually let you define the stack location and size. Put a breakpoint in the start of you program. When the application stops there zero the entire stack. Resume the application and let it work for a while. Finally stop it and inspect the stack memory. You will see non-zero values instead of zeros. The used stack goes until the zeros part starts again.

Comment: For the first part I do have a map produced by gcc using -Map flag, thanks I'll have to go through it, summary info like this:Memory Configuration

Name             Origin             Length             Attributes
rom              0x0000000002000000 0x0000000000400000 xr
ram              0x0000000006000000 0x000000000003fc00 xw
*default*        0x0000000000000000 0xffffffffffffffff

Comment: It doesn't seem my map file contains stack information. Would there be a register or something that might tell me the current location of the stack?

Comment: Yes, that should be in the compiler's documentation, if the version of gcc you use is for embedded applications.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you will have different sections in mmap generated file, where data goes, like :
.intvect

.intvect_end
.rozdata
.robase
.rosdata
.rodata
.text .... and so on!!!

with other attributes like Base,Size(hex),Size(dec) etc for each section.

Comment: There will be other sections available also , mmap gives u the complete picture ... u need to analyse for your limitations !!!

Comment: As i know, .data section has to be analysed for start and end of RAM initialized data ...

Answer (score 0):

While at any time local variables may take up more or less space (as they go in and out of scope), they are instantiated on the stack.  In a single threaded environment, the stack will be a fixed allocation known at link time.  The same is true of all statically allocated data.  The only run-time variable part id dynamically allocated data, but even then sich data is allocated from the heap, which in most bare-metal, single-threaded environments is a fixed link-time allocation.

Consequently all the information you need about memory allocation is probably already provided by your linker.  Often (depending on your tool-chain and linker parameters used) basic information is output when the linker runs.  You can usually request that a full linker map file is generated and this will give you detailed information.  Some linkers can perform stack usage analysis that will give you worst case stack usage for any particular function.  In a single threaded environment, the stack usage from main() will give worst case overall usage (although interrupt handlers need consideration, the linker is not thread or interrupt aware, and some architectures have separate interrupt stacks, some are shared).

Although the heap itself is typically a fixed allocation (often all the available memory after the linker has performed static allocation of stack and static data), if you are using dynamic memory allocation, it may be useful at run-time to know how much memory has been allocated from the heap, as well as information about the number of allocations, average size of allocation, and the number of free blocks and their sizes also.  Because dynamic memory allocation is implemented by your system's standard library any such analysis facility will be specific to your library, and may not be provided at all.  If you have the library source you could implement such facilities yourself.

In a multi-threaded environment, thread stacks may be allocated statically or from the heap, but either way the same analysis methods described above apply.  For stack usage analysis, the worst-case for each thread is measured from the entry point of each thread rather than from main().