# Total space usage by C++ program

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I'm working on a C++ program and I want to find the total memory used by it in its execution. My operating system is Ubuntu 19.10. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871845/determine-total-memory-usage-of-embedded-c-program) as a related question, but it seems to address a much different problem. Any help/directions would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Read `/proc/self/status` or `/proc/self/stat` and then parse the result.

Comment: @Evg is all the information in these files only related to the last program I ran?

Comment: This is the information for the [current process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333225/which-process-is-proc-self-for/333271) (note `self`). You have to read these files from the C++ program itself.

Comment: @Evg I just found this: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/49371?#comment-333749
Isn't this a much easier (and correct?) way?

Comment: The noting of "total memory used" is pretty vague. Depending on what you want exactly, different solutions can be proposed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command line tool `top` to monitor the memory usage of a process. Simply run:

```
top -p PID
```

where `PID` is the process ID of the C++ executable that you want to monitor the memory usage of.

Comment: Okay, can you please tell me how can I find the process id?

Comment: `ps -aux | grep EXECUTABLE`

where EXECUTABLE is the name of your executable.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comments section of your own question, we can use the command line program [GNU `time`](https://www.gnu.org/software/time/) for this.

### note

Though note this method only is useful if you want to know the maximum memory your program has used before it stopped, which can be useful to confirm that an executable you are debugging has an over-time memory leak.

If you want to monitor in real-time then I recommend @spjy's method.

### setup

Obtain it through whatever package manager you have on your linux distro.

Note that by default on a linux system it comes with a default version of time, and thus if you run `time` it will run the default version, not the one you just installed.

If want to run you're installed version you can call it directly `/usr/bin/time`. Then the command you need is

```
/usr/bin/time -v <path to executable>
```

After the command has completed take a look at the line `Maximum resident set size (kbytes)` to see how much memory your program used at most.